# Why $\cosh(y)$ cannot be zero in this example?

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

*"  Find the points $z \in \mathbb{C}$ at which the function $g(z) = \cos(\bar{z})$ satisﬁes the Cauchy-Riemann equations. "*

So I've written $g(z) = g(x,y) = \cos(x-iy)=\cos(x)\cosh(y)+i\sin(x)\sinh(y)$. So that $u(x,y)=\cos(x)\cosh(y)$ and $v(x,y)=\sin(x)\sinh(y)$.

From the first C-R equation I get $-\sin(x)\cosh(y) = \sin(x)\cosh(y)$ which is true when $\sin(x)\cosh(y)=0$.

Now here I thought this implied $\sin(x) = 0$ or $\cosh(y) = 0$. However the solutions give only $\sin(x) = 0$, why?

Also, when doing the second equation, you get $\cos(x)\sinh(y) = 0$, but this time the solutions split the case into $\cos(x)=0$ and $\sinh(y)=0$ as I did above.

Why this?

**EDIT**

Fair enough, I've found this document explaining why it is not zero, as it was said in the comments. 
[Hyperbolic Functions](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/workbooks/mathcentre/hyperbolicfunctions.pdf)

Comment: For real $y$ we have $\cosh(y) \geq \frac 12e^y$, so it doesn't have real roots.

Comment: @LeBtz More precisely, $\cosh(y)\ge 1$.

Comment: So $\cosh(y) =0$ only for complex arguments? Is it $z = \frac{\pi}{2}i +n\pi$ ?

Comment: Yes for the first part, no for the second. The roots are given by $i(\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi), ~n\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Oh yeah it makes sense that also the period is complex, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now here I thought this implied $\sin(x) = 0$ or $\cosh(y) = 0$. However the solutions give only $\sin(x) = 0$, why?

$$ \cosh x = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}2$$

So if $\cosh x = 0$, then $e^x + e^{-x} = 0$.  But this can't happen because both $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ are positive, no matter what real value $x$ has.  And the sum of two positive numbers can never be zero.  Therefore $\cosh x$ can never be zero for real values of $x$.

> Also, when doing the second equation, you get $\cos(x)\sinh(y) = 0$, but this time the solutions split the case into $\cos(x)=0$ and $\sinh(y)=0$ as I did above.
>
> Why this?

$$ \sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}2$$

So if $\sinh x = 0$, then $e^x - e^{-x} = 0$.  And this **can** happen because the difference of two positive numbers can be zero.  And the solution is
\begin{align*}
  e^x - e^{-x} &= 0\\
  e^x &= \frac1{e^x}\\
  e^{2x} &= 1\\
  2x &= \ln 1\\
  x &= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you, that's a perfect explanation!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\cosh^2(y)=1+\sinh^2(y)$$

What happens if $\cosh(y)=0$?

Comment: do we have $y = arcsinh(i)$ ?

Comment: @Euler Yes, but when you write complex numbers in the form $x+iy$ it is always assumed/understood that $y$ is real and hence $\sinh(y)$ is real.

Answer (score 1):

The $\cosh$ of a real number is never zero.